# Mobilefirst 6.3 Css bcakground images not showing In android device

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to use a background image in my mobilefirst project. Everything works fine on web browser and simulator.

But the Background images are not showing in my Android Device.

This is my css code

`.brown-inner {
    background: url("../Images/bg_board_brown_center.png") repeat-y scroll left top transparent;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change "Images" to "images" and it should work.

From:

```
background: url("../Images/bg_board_brown_center.png") ....
```

To:

```
background: url("../images/bg_board_brown_center.png") ....
```

I've done a similar test:

1. Created a new project and application, added the Android environment
2. In my-app\common\css\main.css I added the following:

   ```
   body { background: url("../images/icon.png");}
   ```
3. Launched the app in the Android Emulator. Result:

   [image]

Comment: I just changed  "Images" to "images" but still  the background images are not showing in my Android Device.

Comment: I've tested in a device and it is working. Have you placed the image in the common\images folder in the Worklight project?

Comment: Yes,all background images are placed in common\images folder

Comment: Export your project and upload it to dropbox. Also see my updated answer for a confirmation this is working as expected.

Comment: Thanks Idan. After restarting eclipse and rebulid was solved the issue. Thanks lot...

Comment: I don't think a restart was required, just a re-build, but good to hear. Please mark this as Answered.